# MSP430 - How do I read a grounded I/O pin?

Tags: io, switch-statement, microcontroller, msp430

I have an MSP430 G2452 wired up with several toggle switches (read: NOT buttons). I know how to set up interrupts and debounce a button, but I am having a hard time setting up my port so I can just sample which switches are closed/on.

I want to be able to read P1IN (with masking) to figure out which switches are closed/on and which are open/off. The switches are connected to GND, and I have the pins they're connected to pulled up, so when a switch is closed/on, the pin it's connected to should be pulled down. But P1IN doesn't seem to change.

I am able to set up an interrupt that triggers when a pin is grounded, but I just want to sample the pins, not use an interrupt. How do I set up my port pins so that I can read their states with PxIN?

```
// Port 1 setup
    P1SEL = 0;                  // set P1 as digital I/O for all pins
    P1DIR = ~sw1to6;            // set switches 1-6 for input
    P1OUT = sw1to6;             // enable pull-ups on switches 1-6
    P1REN |= sw1to6;            // enable pull-up resistors on switches 1-6
```

(header file definitions:)

```
// P1.0-1.5
#define sw1 0x01
#define sw2 0x02
#define sw3 0x04
#define sw4 0x08
#define sw5 0x10
#define sw6 0x20
#define sw1to6 sw1 | sw2 | sw3 | sw4 | sw5 | sw6
```

Comment: Side note: all the searches I tried gave me info on how to debounce a button input.

Comment: You gave the answer. With that setup you can read P1IN.

Comment: What code did you use to try to actually read the port, what happened when you did so, and what did you expect to happen instead?

Comment: http://github.com/dwelch67/msp430_samples may have what you are interested in.  To debug your problem try polling the input pin and write the state of that pin to perhaps an led on an output pin, then press the button and see if the led changes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since your "sw1to6" macro is not in parenthesis the negation will not do what you expect. You probably want:

```
#define sw1to6 (sw1 | sw2 | sw3 | sw4 | sw5 | sw6)
```

In general it is best to always put your macros in parenthesis.

After that you should be able to read the pins on P1IN.

Comment: I will try this out as soon as I get a chance. As a side question, do you know how it *does* behave without parenthesis?

Comment: Sweet, this was my problem. Thanks!